# Find the Generating Function from the sequence (0,1,0,3,0,5,...)

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the Generating Function from the sequence (0,1,0,3,0,5,...)

I can't conceptualize this one and I know it should be easy because it is just odds, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to cancel the even terms.

I was thinking like k$x^k$ but that doesn't cancel the evens.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots$ then what is $f(x) - f(-x)$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$G(x)=x+3x^3+5x^5+...=x(1+3x^2+5x^4+...)= xF'(x),$
where $$F(x)=x+x^3+x^5+...=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$
I'm sure you can finish from here.

Comment: That seems like a very complicated way of expressing `(x mod 2) * x`.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (2i+1)x^{2i+1} =\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{2x^3}{(1-x^2)^2} = \frac{x+x^3}{(1-x^2)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What's up with the floating cube? Should that be $2x^3$ ?

Comment: @mr_e_man You are right ... It is a mr_e why I did not put the $2x$ in !

Answer (score -2):

The answer is simple.
Just iterate for x = 0 to Infinite
And the `xth` term is

```
f(x) = (x%2)*x
```

Where % is modulus operator which returns the remainder of the two operands

Here x%2 cancels out all the even terms leaving all the odd terms behind

Comment: Yes, but that's not the generating function.  The generating function is a formal power series.